# How to fill missing dates with time in range?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

I have table which has date with time and one column with values. Every 10sec the table should get a new record. It looks like:

```
Date                      Val1
2020-10-03 10:12:21       30
2020-10-03 10:12:31       30
2020-10-03 10:12:41       30
2020-10-03 10:12:51       30
2020-10-03 10:13:01       30
...
2020-12-07 10:13:24       20
2020-12-07 10:13:34       20
```

I need to check what the values were between dates, for example:
from 2020-10-03 10:00 to 2020-12-07 12:30,
every 5/15/30 minutes or 1h:

```
Date                   Val1
2020-10-03 10:00       30
2020-10-03 10:30       30
2020-10-03 11:00       30
2020-10-03 11:30       30
2020-10-03 12:00       30
...
2020-12-07 12:00       20
2020-12-07 12:30       20
```

I was trying to do it in MySQL with:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") as Date, Val1
FROM table 
WHERE Date >= "2020-10-03 10:00" AND Date <= "2020-12-07 12:30" 
GROUP BY unix_timestamp(Date) 
DIV 1800
```

but it's not working very well if I don't have every datetime.

How to fill missing dates with NULL value? I need every minute
(if interval is in minutes, every hour if interval is in hour).

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It seems that you have deleted previous version of this question with all its comments instead of editing it. *How to fill missing dates with NULL value?* Generate this dates list and join with your data.

Comment: @Akina I am new in MySQL, I don't really know how to do that correct. Also, I prefer find solution without create new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query to generate the date range, then bring the table with a `left join`:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select '2020-10-03 10:00:00' dt
    union all select dt + interval 1 minute from cte where dt < '2020-12-07 12:30:00'
)
select c.dt, avg(t.val1) as val1
from cte c
left join mytable t on t.date >= c.dt and t.date < c.dt + interval 1 minute
group by c.dt
```

When there are several records within a given minute, this takes the average of `val1`. In that regard, this fixes your original query, which was missing an aggregate function on `val1`.

Comment: I have 10+ ver. I had error mytable.cte doesn't exist. I added  RECURSIVE before cte and it started works but It took a lot of time and it ended with error: 504 Gateway Timeout

Comment: @Justyna: indeed we need `recursive` in MySQL. Fixed. As for the timeout problem, I cannot really tell. Does it work when you change the interval to `interval 1 hour` for example (in both places where it appears)?

Comment: Yes, it works very well If I have more than 1 minutes. This solved my problem - about Gateway I have to find another solution. For this, I am very grateful to you! Greetings :)